# Bundle packages with a document

Tags: packages

I'd like to have my LaTeX document be self-contained, that is, if I move to another computer I'd like all of my non-standard packages to work without first installing them. For simple enough packages I can put the `.sty` files into the base directory, but this seems like a clunky solution. I can put the packages in a subdirectory but I sometimes than I get dependency errors like

```
 LaTeX Warning: You have requested package style_files/placeins
 but the package provides `placeins'.

 (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
```

Is there a right way (tm) to do this, or should I install every package I need on every computer I use?

Comment: Your "dependency errors" are *warnings*, i.e. you could simply ignore them. You seem to load `placeins` using `\usepackage{style_files/placeins}`. To avoid this you can add the `style_files` directory to the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at Scott Pakin's scripts on CTAN under [`bundledoc`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/bundledoc/).  `bundledoc` is a perl script that gathers all the dependent files to processing a single file and puts them in a single directory, then zips it up for easy transport.

Comment: Excellent! I think I'll be able to learn a lot of what is required for my question by observing what the Perl script does. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any version of it for Windows? It just says about Unix/Linux

Answer (score 4):

Apart from placing them into the document directory and installing them into the main directory you can also create a own `texmf` directory structure which is automatically searched by (La)TeX. Under Unix/Linux OSs it is normally `~/texmf` (i.e. the directory `texmf` in your home directory). With Windows+MikTeX it is IIRC `c:\\localtexmf`. There LaTeX packages are normally placed in the directories `./tex/latex/<package name>/` like in the main tree. So e.g. `placeins` would be in `~/texmf/tex/latex/placeins/placeins.sty`. You don't have to create subfolders for every package, but the `tex/latex` part should be kept.

You could just create a `~/texmf/tex/latex/mystuff` directory and place all the extra packages you use in there. Then you only need to synchronize/copy the `~/texmf` folder to any computer you use. (La)TeX will pick them up there automatically without any warnings or errors.

PS:
On the other side I simply recommend you to install TeXLive manually (i.e. not using the OS provided packages, like the one of Ubuntu) and completely. The used size (about 2.8GB) shouldn't be a problem with modern hard drive sizes and it saves you these and other issues.

Comment: Will the packages be found automatically, or does an additional command need to be run (like `texhash`)? The reason I ask is that I want as much as possible to run \emph{out of the box}. The ideal situation would be to walk over to another computer with only a basic (La)TeX installation and put my document in from a thumb drive, without modifying anything on the local computer.

Comment: @Hooked: Modern versions of TeXLive do scan the user's `texmf` directory structure automatically. However, the file which `texhash` generates is anyway inside that directory. You can set the `TEXMFHOME` environment variable to the `texmf` dir on your USB stick.