# Use package from same dir as source

Tags: packages, compiling

For college, we are supposed to hand in uncompiled `.tex` files for the teacher to make the `.pdf` themselves. However, college computers have very few packages installed ; but I have heard somewhere that one can include the package along with the `.tex` source. I cannot find a guide on how to do this, can someone explain how or provide a link for me ?

I am *not* asking how to normally use packages, rather how to include them for compilation on a system where installing packages directly is *not possible*.

Comment: It's probably worth asking your teacher, what you could in theory do vs what they will allow/do in practice are different questions.  It may be they only want certain packages to be used, or they may be compiling on a separate full distribution.

Comment: TeX distributions usually find files in the document directory first. So, e.g., an `article.cls` file in the document directory would be used, even if the TeX distribution itself has a file with the same name. However, adding package files that are usually provided by the TeX distribution to the document directory is not really a good idea, but a source of difficult-to-assess problems in the medium to long term.

Comment: just place the .sty in the same folder and it will be loaded. but some packages are just one file  some like tikz are dozens and some require fonts...

Comment: [Bundle packages with a document - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14520/bundle-packages-with-a-document#comment26898_14533) but it may or may not work